# Error al anidad un bucle v-for - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, html5, vue.js

estoy realizando una tarjeta de pregunta con Vue.js usando props y ciclos v-for. El problema que se presenta es que cuando intento acceder a los datos de un array que he llamado `opciones`, simplemente no se me muestra nada en pantalla y la consola no me marca ningún error, agradezco me puedan orientar, a continuación compartiré mi código para que puedan ver de qué se trata:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="style.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">
                <pregunta  :preguntas = "preguntas"></pregunta>
            </div>
         </div>
        
    </main>
   


    <script src="./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./pregunta.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const pregunta ={
    template : ` <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card margenes">
            <div class="card-header" v-for="question in preguntas" >
               <p>Pregunta : {{question.pregunta}}</p> 
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-check" v-for="option in preguntas.opciones">
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1" >
                     <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1" >
                        {{option.opcion}}
                      </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>`,
props: ['preguntas']
}

var app = new Vue({
  el : 'main',
  data :{
    preguntas : [
        {
          pregunta : "De que color es la casa de pepe?",
          opciones : [
               {opcion : 'blanca'},
               {opcion : 'azul'},
               {opcion : 'verde'},
               {opcion : 'cafe'},
          ],
          
          
             
        }
    ]
  },
  components :{
    pregunta : pregunta
  }

})
```

Comment: Puede que te falte return en la data de tu componente, fijate bien la estructura https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#single-file-components

Comment: @Eme, El usuario esta usando Declarative Rendering/straightforward template syntax, donde vue no devuelve el estado reactivo

Comment: Tendrías que tener el segundo for anidado en el primero, o sea dentro del div, y hacer `v-for="option in question.opciones"`, ya que `opciones` es una propiedad al mismo nivel que `pregunta`